# strftime and nonnormalized dates/times

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strftime

Most definitions of `strftime`'s `%H`, `%M`, and `%S` specifiers (including those in the ANSI/ISO C Standards) contain language like

> `%H`   is replaced by the hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number (00-23).

Now, that little notation "(00-23)" at the end tells you the
range of numbers you're going to see *if the `struct tm` you're
printing was just created by `localtime` or `gmtime`*.

My question concerns the presence or absence of a requirement
that the `struct tm` being referenced by `strftime` *must* have been
one just generated by `localtime` or `gmtime`.  I don't think there's
such a requirement, but if there isn't, those notations "(00-23)"
and "(00-59)" don't really have any normative implications for
strftime -- they're more of a misplaced requirement on the values
generated by `localtime` and `gmtime`.

But if `strftime` doesn't restrict the ranges of the various `struct tm`
fields to their "normal" values, it makes me wonder how much
latitude a push-the-boundaries programmer actually has when
calling `strftime`.  Are the values as unlimited as they are when
calling, say, `mktime`?

To make the question more concrete, it came to me when I found
myself writing this code:

```
time_t dt = t2 - t1;
struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&dt);
if(dt > 86400)
    tmp->tm_hour += dt / 86400 * 24;
strftime(etbuf, sizeof(etbuf), "elapsed: %H:%M:%S", tmp);
```

That is, I'm subtracting two times, and letting `gmtime` and
`strftime` convert the difference to HH:MM:SS format for me.
But if the time delta was more than a day, I'm not printing it
as days; I'm just lumping it in with the hours (which, it's true,
might end up being a very large number if there were months or
years between `t1` and `t2`).

So, language lawyer question: Is this legal and portable?
When calling `strftime`, are `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, and the rest
limited to their normal ranges, or not?  (Yes, I've tried it,
and nonnormalized values work -- not at all surprisingly --
as expected under the popular implementations, but that's not
the question.)

[Full disclosure: I am posting the [same question](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2018-July/026572.html) to the [tz mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/listinfo/tz).]

Comment: Did values over 99 work?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C11 standard 7.27.3.5/3 says:

> If any of the specified values is outside the normal range, the characters stored are unspecified.

Which I take to mean that the input must be normalized for the function to behave correctly; and a conforming implementation of `strftime` might operate by naively reading and displaying the values stored in the struct without performing any analysis on them.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I'm mildly disappointed, but not surprised. At least it's not undefined.