# How are conflicts in struct tm members resolved?

Tags: c, struct, time

`time.h` declares `struct tm` that has (amongst other members) the following:

```
int         tm_mon;    /* Month            [0, 11]  (January = 0) */
int         tm_mday;   /* Day of the month [1, 31] */
int         tm_wday;   /* Day of the week  [0, 6]   (Sunday = 0) */
int         tm_yday;   /* Day of the year  [0, 365] (Jan/01 = 0) */
```

A structure like this allows you to get into impossible situations... for example:

`tm_mon=0 ; tm_mday=1 ; tm_yday=360`

or

`tm_year=0 ; tm_yday=1 ; tm_wday=5 ;  // January 1, 1900 is on a Monday`

I've had good luck `memset`ting the structure to 0s and then only setting the fields I want to set.

My question is:  Is there a deterministic way that `struct tm` should be interpreted?

I've been experimenting with this for awhile, so this isn't a "how can I get my code to work" question.  Mostly, I'm asking about other experienced programmers' experience with `struct tm` and fish for any gotchas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a deterministic way that `struct tm` should be interpreted?

Yes, *mostly*.

Call `mktime()` to resolve those  *impossible situations* in `struct tm`.

As well mention by [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75478609/2410359), calling `mktime()` will ignore members `.tm_wday` and `.tm_yday` and proceed to resolve other member combinations that are out of the normal range as if the time was a *local time*.

Unusual "gotcha" time stamp examples include:

- One member is out of primary range: reduce to the primary range and add the excess to the next most significant member.  Repeat as needed.  See later exception.
- February  29, (non-leap year).
- `.tm_min = 30, .tm_isdst < 0` and `.tm_hour` is in the missing hour of a 23-hour day when the zone goes on *daylight time* (DST).
- `.tm_min = 30, .tm_isdst < 0` and `.tm_hour` is in the added hour of a 25-hour day when the zone goes off *daylight time*.
- I have doubt about the reliability of `mktime()` to handle pathological cases like `.tm_year = INT_MAX/12 + 100, .tm_mon = INT_MIN`.  Such extremes may show different resolutions (or a error return value of -1) on various platforms and reflect a quality of implementation difference.
- `mktime()` returns -1 to indicate an error.  Unfortunately it can also rarely return -1 to indicate a valid time.  C spec offers no clear way to distinguish.
- `struct tm` may have other members than the specified 9.  I have seen `.tm_nsecs, .tm_usec, .tm_timezone, .tm_tzoffset` or equivalents.  That is why it is best to initialize with `{ 0 }` or first `memset(0)` the entire object when populating a `struct tm` with custom code.
- The trickiest ones - when `.tm_year, .tm_mon, .tm_mday` are all out of range: Which to resolve first?  Depending on order, the result differs.  C does specify:

> the final value of `tm_mday` is not set until `tm_mon` and `tm_year` are determined.

---

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) does allow `24:00:00` to refer to the instant at the end of a calendar day.  That is the same time `0:00:00` of the next day. So sometimes, reducing via `mktime()` is not always desirable.

---

For simplicity and sanity's sake, discussion about [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) ignored.

Answer (score 1):

as per man page for `mktime` (the only thing that reads a tm)

> The values of the members tm_wday and tm_yday of timeptr are ignored,

when reading a tm - from `localtime`, say, all fields are set. Its up to you to choose which ones are interesting

Comment: Excellent!  That makes a lot of sense.  Thank you.

Comment: @MarkNelson - if all else fails read the manual :-)

Comment: `mktime()` is not the only standard library function that consumes `struct tm` objects.  `asctime()` does too, and `asctime_r()` if you want to include POSIX additions.  These do not specify either directly or indirectly any particulars of how they interpret an inconsistent `struct tm`.  Perhaps they will do the same as `mktime()`, perhaps not.

Comment: Also `strftime()`, which, given its specific nature, seems a particularly good candidate for exercising different behavior.

Comment: To that point, see [strftime and nonnormalized dates/times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145727).